# 22.04.1 LTS - Err: https://llvm.org/apt/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial Release

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, compiling

I am trying to update LLVM latest source list with the latest packages from the repositories.

when doing `llvm-config --version` I get: **14.0.0**

When doing `sudo apt update` OR `sudo apt-get update` I get the below error.

```
Hit:10 https://apt.llvm.org/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 InRelease  
Ign:7 https://llvm.org/apt/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial InRelease       
Ign:9 https://llvm.org/apt/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 InRelease
Err:11 https://llvm.org/apt/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial Release
  Redirection from https to 'http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/dists/llvm-toolchain-xenial/Release' is forbidden
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: talk to llvm.org?  They're trying to downgrade from https connection to http which is not permitted, so the question then is why do you have https:// in there when they don't want that to work

Comment: Also, Xenial is 16.04 while you are using 22.04. You have added packages for a wrong version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi thank you. I will start by removing them.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by restoring my VM to a date prior to installing LLVM packages. To re-install LLVM I followed the LLVM page https://apt.llvm.org/. I followed the instructions under headings 'Automatic installation script' and 'Default packages'.